# Git pull while on a deleted branch

Tags: git, version-control, git-pull

Let's say I have branch named 'feature1' checked out. At origin, unbeknownst to me, someone had deleted that branch. What are the results of doing a `git pull` while I am sitting on this deleted branch? Will I be moved to a different branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your branches are *yours*.  No one but you can delete them!

If your branch `feature1` has `origin/feature1` as its upstream, and `feature1` has been deleted on `origin`, then one of the things will happen when you run `git fetch origin`:

- Nothing.  Your `origin/feature1` will continue to exist.  Since there is no `feature1` on `origin` for your `origin/feature1` to remember, your Git's `origin/feature1` just sits there, unchanged, forever.
- Since there is no `feature1` on `origin` any more, *and* you've set the "prune" option, your Git will delete your `origin/feature1`.  Your own `feature1` now has a nonexistent `origin/feature1` as its upstream.

Which of these happens, of course, depends on whether you set the prune option (by running `git fetch --prune origin`, for instance, or setting `fetch.prune` to `true` in your configuration).

Note that `git pull` simply runs `git fetch`—which does one of those two things—and then normally runs `git merge` based on what got fetched.  Since *nothing* will get fetched, the second step of the two-part `pull` command will simply fail.  (This is the case whether or not you specify pruning—the *fetch* step didn't see anything named `feature1` on `origin`, and the pull code notices that fact.)

Answer (score 2):

Nothing would happen that would impact your local repo. And you wouldn't be switched to a different branch.

Here's the actual info you get back when doing a `git pull` on a deleted branch (assuming it was set up to track the remote branch of the same name): 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are on `feature1` and do `git pull`, nothing will happen. Beyond Git failing to do pull. You will get an error about not being able to find the remote ref (because it was deleted). Your `feature1` branch remains unchanged.

You are not "sitting on this deleted branch" because it was deleted at the origin, which does not impact your local repo. You are sitting on a branch that does not track a remote branch.